# Reponse of post request slow

Tags: java

I'm not trying to expose too many details of what I am trying to make, but basically I have a bot that sends a post request at a certain time. Basically, I'm racing against other people to send this post request first. When I test this code against no one, it gets responses almost instant. However, it seems when I go for these post requests against more people, it takes longer than  normal to get a response.

Code to open connection:

```
  httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (proxy != null ? url.openConnection(proxy) : url.openConnection());
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

Code to get response:

```
  @SneakyThrows
    public String getResponse() {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String responseLine = null;
            while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(responseLine.trim());
            }
            return response.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the high response time is caused by the client?

Comment: Have you done any profiling to see if the code is causing the slow response? Is it possible the service you're communicating with is processing requests slower because of the influx in requests?

Comment: that would most likely be an issue on the server, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect the slowdown is on your end, you can try something like Jprofiler in order to determine what is causing your code to run slow. However, based on what you've said, it's very likely that it's simply the server being slow to respond. If you print or log when the request is sent and when the response is received, I suspect you'll find most of the time is there, waiting on the server to respond.